# How to print BOOLs

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I want to print a BOOL (which is documented to be a signed char) without any compiler warnings:

```
NSLog(@"Parsing Result = %hhd", parsingResult);

//  inside some iOS program. Xocde 6
```

But I get "Format specifies type 'char' but the argument has type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')".

Comment: Try `%d`, that's what I always use.

Comment: No, BOOL is not signed char. It actually has different types on 32 and 64 bit machines. I always use %@ and (parsingResult ? @"YES" : @"NO").

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSLog(parsingResult ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: This should be more like: `NSLog(@"%@", parsingResult ? @"YES" : @"NO");`

Comment: The `%@` is unnecessary as the result of the ternary operator replaces the condition, but of course, both are correct.

Comment: You missed the point. `NSLog` is much like `stringWithFormat:`. The first argument to `NSLog` should be a string containing some combination of text and format specifiers. Then there should be enough arguments for the format specifiers (if any).

Comment: I agree, but in this case the argument to `NSLog` is essentially still either a `@"YES"` or a `@"NO"`, so it doesn't make a difference. I could do the same with `NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:parsingResult ? @"YES" : @"NO"];`.